# htaccess redirect only specific folder to another domain with same specific folder for Magento not working

Tags: .htaccess, url, magento, redirect

I am trying to redirect domain-1.org/store/* to domain1.org/store/*

- *=anything after store/ should be added to the end of the URL redirect.

Here is the htaccess rule I wrote:

   Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
   RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www.)?domain-1.org$ [NC]
 
RewriteRule ^store-([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ http://www.domain1.org/store$1/ [R=301,L]

This doesn't work. It just redirects everything to the root /store/ folder.

Somewhere either in Magento code (or on our server but I highly doubt it because it is not in the httpd.conf or the custom_vhosts.conf) there is a blanket redirect that redirects domain-1.org/store/* to domain1.org/store root instead of to the relative same path.

These are the problems it is causing:

I am trying to force the redirect in .htaccess on the root of the server and in the root magento folder, neither rules are applied.  I have read and tried so many different HTACCESS rules, and none of them seem to work.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue here is you're trying to match both www and without www but you're using a conditional group. I think this could easily be accomplished by having the group as optional with regex. Try this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain-1.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^store-([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ http://www.domain1.org/store$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.  It didn't work but I think it has to do with Magento Enterprise.  Do you know anything about how magento controls redirects and how it could interphere with this? I put this on my site and it is still just redirecting all urls to /store root folder.

Comment: Magento controls redirects from within Catalog > URL Rewrite Management. However, you can force your rewrite behavior ahead of Magento's by putting the above rule near the top of your .htaccess file in your web root.

Comment: Thanks Phil! From what I can tell URL Rewrite Management in Magento is only from within to domain, not cross domain.  How can I find out what other rules might be conflicting?  On my apache server I have checked in the httpd.conf and the custom_vhosts.conf, but there is no reference to this, however if I have no rules in my .htaccess there is still a redirect happenning.  Where else can I look?

Comment: Are URL redirects happening at all? Can you prove this? I would look in your httpd.conf file and verify that your vhost has "AllowOverride" set to "All".

Comment: Second thing to check is if your Apache instance has the mod_rewrite module enabled by issuing the following command at the prompt: `a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: URL redirects are happenning. THis is from my httpd.conf file:
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit

    AllowOverride All

Comment: Also mod_rewrite is enabled.  I am using other rewrites in Joomla on this server, as well as Magento that uses it for internal re-writes.

Comment: You may be on to something.  URL redirects are happenning. I have this for my enabled for the folder one level up <Directory "/var/www/">.  Do i have to enable it for the specific "<Directory "/var/www/store>" folder seperately where Magento is installed?

Comment: You shouldn't have to, but go ahead and define it to see if it works. If we need further discussion let's move it to chat.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, and I don't have enough rep to do chat.  I will try to improve that :)  Let me know if you have any other ideas.